# Can't add values to List (Count is always 1) - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list

Many times I  had to create lists of structures to store my data in C#. But this time, I have a problem, I can't seem to be able to add values to my list. I don't quite understand why, since I already did similar projects, but I would be very appreciated if someone could help me.

```
class mng
{
    int day = 0;
    List<Despesas> dias = new List<Despesas>();

    public struct Despesas
    {
        public double transportes;
        public double agua;
    }        

    public mng ()
    {
    }

 public void addValues(double transportes, double agua)
    {            
        Despesas dia = new Despesas();
        try
        {
            dia.transportes = transportes;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

         try
        {
            dia.agua = agua;
         }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

         try
         {
             dias.Add(dia);
         }
         catch
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         }

        MessageBox.Show("Added: " + dias.Count);
        day++;
    }
```

and on Form1:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   try{     
    double transportes = Convert.ToDouble(txtTransportes.Text);
    double agua = Convert.ToDouble(txtAgua.Text);
    mng mngV = new mng();
             mngV.addValues(transportes, agua);
       }
   catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
       }
```

On the overload constructor I have a message that shows the count of the list values every time a new one is added and guess value is always 1 and I just don't understand why.

The only thing different from this project to the other similar projects I've done and work is that this project has 2 forms, I don't think that has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Your creating a new mng each time. So day is always zero. Should it be static (across all classes) or should you not be creating new mngs? Also why are there so many identical catch blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On the overload constructor I have a message that shows the count of the list values every time a new one is added and guess value is always 1 and I just don't understand why.

That's because each time you create a new instance of `mng` (which should be given a more meaningful and conventional name, by the way) you're creating a *new* list, which is empty to start with. You're adding one item to it, so the count is 1.

If you want to share a single list between multiple instances of `mng`, you should *possibly* make the `dias` variable static (in which case it's not associated with *any* specific instance) or you could pass a reference into the constructor.

Alternatively, perhaps you don't really want to create a new instance of `mng` at all - perhaps you should be calling a *method* on an existing instance? It's hard to know without more context.

As a side-note, I would strongly urge you to avoid public fields and mutable structs (your `Despesas` type).

Comment: My goal is to call a method from another class. So I always do something like Class1 myClass = new Class1(); myClass.function();

Comment: @MiguelPT: But do you *want* to call the method on a new instance? Or do you want to call it on an existing instance, e.g. one you've previously added other values to? It sounds like you really need to think about the objects involved, when when you want to create new ones.

Comment: Please look at my updated code. I just want to read the values transportes and agua from a textBox in form 1 and pass the values to the another class. So on Form1 I call a method "addValues" to pass them values to another class and add to the list.

Comment: @MiguelPT: Your edit changes a constructor to a method - but you're still creating a new instance before calling the method... so how do you expect the count to ever be more than one? Again, we don't really know what you're trying to achieve - you're not *doing* anything with the instance after you've added the value. (You also need to work on your exception handling - your code is *littered* with try/catch blocks at the moment, which are making it far more complicated than it needs to be.)

Comment: Jesus, thank you and sorry, but coming from objective-C and C I'm actually having a bad time learning C#...too different from the other two, I was expecting more similarities :s